# Could not load file or assembly 'MWArray' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, asp.net, matlab

When ever im trying to run my matlab with Asp.NET i'm getting

> "Could not load file or assembly 'MWArray' or one of its dependencies.
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

error. I tried to change CPU from x86 to x64 to Any CPU but none of them working. Even i configured IIS server but fail to load assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I am referencing this dll too and here are my configuration of the project that references it that actually work:

[image]

I don't know exactly what your configuration, it would help if you add more info.
Can you make console app and try if this configuration works, then continue to web app like you actually do.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 64bit and Matlab R2011a 64bit. I tried this program on Windows 7 also, but the result was the same. My configuration is same as shown in above pic.

Comment: Even i tried this code to register                                                             GAC  gacutil /i "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\toolbox\dotnetbuilder\bin\win64\v2.0\MWarray.dll"

Comment: Do you have success when referencing MWarray.dll in console application project and not Asp.NET project?

Comment: No, I'm getting error in console. here is my error code System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.at ConsoleApplication4.Program.applyNoise(MWArray mWArray) in c:\Users\Sunil\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs:line 64
   at ConsoleApplication4.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Sunil\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs:line 39

Comment: I refered this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241067/matlab-dll-integration-with-asp-net-website-in-64-bit-machine-giving-exception but none of them worked

Comment: Pls post your Console application code, also minimize it so you have the error message with minimal code.

Comment: MWNumericArray matrix1 = null;
MWNumericArray matrix2 = null;
MWArray res = null;
matrix1 = new MWNumericArray(new double[4, 4]);
matrix2 = new MWNumericArray(new double[4, 4]);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
                {
                    matrix1[i,j] = j * 3;
                    matrix2[i,j] = j * 3 + 2;
                } }
            MatrixExampleclass test = new MatrixExampleclass();
            res=test.addMe((MWArray)matrix1, (MWArray)matrix2);
            Console.WriteLine("Sum is: ",res);
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: above is my code and my matlab code is  function [res]=addMe(A,B)
     res=A+B;
end